# Poking a character into a parent process's buffer

Tags: c, shell, terminal, automated-tests

I am trying to write a program that runs in the background that can "type" into a parent process, e.g. issue shell commands as if I had typed them myself at the keyboard. I have tried doing this with `ungetc()` to push back to `STDIN`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
        ungetc('x', stdin);
        return 0;
}
```

I would expect that doing:

```
$ gcc -o unget unget.c
$ ./unget&
```

Would have left me at the `$` prompt with `x` there as if I'd just typed it, but instead I get nothing. Have I "lost" `STDIN` by going into the background? Thanks!

Comment: Are you attempting to accomplish IPC or is this a prof of concept.

Comment: It's to "be me" and drive an interactive session unattended. For assorted reasons I cannot just use Expect in this environment. I also need to leave the terminal free so I can enter commands into it if necessary myself, hence the background process.

Comment: E.g. I might want it to run a command on my behalf every x minutes, while I continue to do stuff in the foreground, but it has to be as if it comes from my shell so PPID works out correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This second answer is not so much an answer to your question as written, but to the problem you're trying to solve. It's much more robust than sending keystrokes to your shell.

In the shell, use the `trap` command to setup a signal handler. For example:

```
trap "echo hello" USR2
```

Replace `USR2` with whatever signal you want to use. Then run a child process that periodically sends the signal to its parent.

Comment: Also note that you can implement the child as a shell script: `( while : ; do sleep 30 ; kill -USR2 $PPID ; done ) & child_pid=$!`

Answer (score 4):

What you're trying to do simply cannot work. `ungetc` operates on the stdio `FILE` buffer, not the underlying open file description, and thus there is no way for it to be shared with another process.

You might try running the interactive session in `screen` and using screen's `exec` command to redirect file descriptors through a process that will inject data. Or you could implement something like this yourself using pseudo-tty devices.

Further, from your comments, I think what you're trying to do is an extremely bad idea. If you get unlucky and the input comes in the middle of you typing something interactively, it could have disastrous consequences. For instance imaging the automated command is

```
command_foo my_important_file
```

Now suppose you're in the middle of typing

```
rm -rf useless_crap
```

**Bam**! `my_important_file` just got deleted.

Comment: +1, pseudo-ttys is probably the solution. For a test driver, I'd investigate using expect instead of wrapping pseudo-ttys myself.

Comment: There's a nonstandard but convenient function `forkpty` that makes running a child process wrapped in a pseudo-tty extremely easy. On systems that don't have it, you can implement it easily in terms of the standard functions (though sadly the standard functions are non-thread-safe and POSIX hasn't bothered to adopt any solution to that problem...).

Comment: Also see my other answer for a completely different approach that's actually safe.

Answer (score 1):

No -- `ungetc` only "pushes" the character back into the programs *own* buffer, so when the next character that same program reads will be what was passed to `ungetc`. Transmitting something back to the parent requires something entirely different (e.g., creating some pipes).

Comment: Pipes can't do what OP wants; only a pseudo-tty device, and only under the opposite parent/child relationship or a sibling-like relationship, can do what OP wants.

Comment: @R. Well, sort of true. If a parent wants to badly enough, it can use `dup2` to connect its stdin to a dhild's stdout. I'm not sure why you'd do that, but I'm pretty it would work if you did.

Comment: You can't just "connect" file descriptors like this and get pipe-like behavior; you'd need a pipe (which would break interactive behavior) or a pseudo-tty.

Answer (score 0):

Just off the top of my head, maybe you could tweak the pipes of your terminal so that the cout of your child is cin for the parent. In bash it would go something like this:

```
exec 6>&1
exec 7<&0
exec 1>&7
exec 0<&6
```

Then when you start your programs the pipes should be inverted. So everything you put into cout should come out at cin from your parent (the bash process in this case).

Comment: Since he is executing in background he could switch them back. The child's pipes would still be switched.